# Google analytics API Implementation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, google-api

I try to implement the google analytics api in my project. I use javascript API for this and I create google api and I followed the steps on the link below and the code is the same.

[Hello Analytics API: JavaScript quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js)

But it does not work and I'm getting an error like these :

1-) Uncaught -> uO message: "Invalid cookiePolicy" stack:"gapi.auth2.ExtarnallyVisibleError an new uO (https://apis.google.com/_/js/...)"

2-) Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run this in a local file. Try putting this on a (public-facing) webserver.

Comment: Thanks @eike-pierstorff As you said, the problem is solved when I try on the web server.